# How to use doccano-transformer generator output?

Tags: python, annotations, spacy, named-entity-recognition, doccano

Doccano is an annotation tool for data to use in machine learning.
Its creator has also developed the doccano-transformer which is used to transform the format of the JSONL output that doccano gives to the spacy format.

Here is the Github https://github.com/doccano/doccano-transformer

The code :

```
dataset.to_spacy(tokenizer=str.split)
```

gives me a "generator" object and I don't know what to do with it. It is surely not the expected "spacy" object. So I wonder if anyone has a clue on how to convert this generator into spacy ?